# Image is not successfully compiling on react app

Tags: reactjs

I posted a similar question today but for some reason, I can't seem to get the paths right on React. I'm trying to import an image but I get this error  `Can't resolve '../assets/heroImage.jpg' in '/Users/joanaleitaooliveira/repos/web-project/src/components/Jumbrotron'`

As you can see, the image "heroImage.jpg" is inside the file "assets" so I'm not sure why is this not working.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

the path should be ../../assets/heroImage.jpg